# Nhibernate PrimaryKey must be unique

Tags: c#, nhibernate, hibernate, primary-key

I've set up a Nhibernate Project in C# with a Local SQLite Database, and if got an issue while saving my Nhibernate object, it says me that my primarykey is not unique, thats right but i added a Generator to my nhibernate-mapping.

Here is the Class:

```
  public class Article
      {

          public virtual int ArticleId { get; set; }
          public virtual string Name { get; set; }
          public virtual double Price { get; set; }
          public virtual string ArticleNumber { get; set; }
          public virtual string Description { get; set; }

          public virtual Sales Sales {get; set;}
     }
```

And here is the Mapping File:

```
<class name="Article">
    <id name="ArticleId">
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="Name" />
    <property name="Price" />
    <property name="ArticleNumber" />
    <property name="Description" />

    <many-to-one name="Sales" class="Sales" column="SalesId"/>

</class>
```

Im Creating Some Articles, and im adding it to Sales, if i want to save my Sales, it got this PrimaryKey exception.

Is there a known issue?

Very Thanks, Alex

Sales Mapping:

```
<class name="Sales">
    <id name="SaleId" unsaved-value="0">
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="Amount" />
    <property name="Price" />

    <bag name="OrderList" cascade="all">
      <key column="ArticleId"/>
      <one-to-many class="Article"/>
    </bag>

  </class>

public class Sales
    {
        public Sales()
        {
            if (this.orderList == null)
                orderList = new List<Article>();
        }

        private IList<Article> orderList;

        public virtual int SaleId { get; set; }
        public virtual double Price { get; set; }
        public virtual int Amount { get; set; }

        public virtual IList<Article> OrderList 
        {
            get
            {
                return this.orderList;
            }
            set
            {

                this.orderList = value;
            }
        }
   }
```

Comment: How is your database schema being generated? Is the PK created as an identity column?

Comment: Nhibernate is creating the Database Schema (: im not connecting to an existing database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest setting up your identity mapping as such:

```
<id name="ArticleId" unsaved-value="0">
  <generator class="native" />
</id>
```

Ensure the PK field is an identity field.

Then in your mapping for Sales:

```
<many-to-one name="Sales" class="Sales" column="SalesId" insert="true" update="true"/>
```

Same thing for your Sales mapping.  Ensure it's id mapping has an unsaved value of 0 and the PK is marked as an identity field.

Comment: Should i Implement the same changes on the other side?

Comment: Yes.  If you can, post your Sales mapping file.

Comment: I've added the Sales Mapping to the Post, the unsaved-value="0" attribute is new

Comment: Oh, i've fixed a little bug, the Column identity for the <many-to-one> mapping is SaleId, but it doesnt fixed the other problem

Comment: The bag "OrderList" should be set with Inverse="False".  I think what's happening is the Sales entity is saving the Article, which then attempts to save the Sales object.

Comment: Hmm... Ensure your syntax is correct.  Check out http://bchavez.bitarmory.com/archive/2007/10/06/nhibernate-and-inversetruefalse-attribute.aspx for details on bilateral relationships.

Comment: Sales:
<one-to-many class="Article" inverse="true" />
Article:
<many-to-one name="Sales" class="Sales" column="SaleId" inverse="false" insert="true" update="true"/>

I cant find any Syntax Problems :(

Answer (score 0):

the problem was that i was using a Transaction, without Transaction it worked very well.

Thanks Jeffrey Jochum for your help.